# Getting error "Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'" despite it being in the bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, sqlite

I have a ASP.Net Web Project and used NuGet to include System.Data.SQLite.

That shows under my references but when I publish my app (via "File System") and go to the controller "http://localhost/api/test", it shows the error:

> Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' The specified module could not be found.

I noticed, in my project's `bin\Release\net452\win7-x86\x64` the DLL is there, but in the website's actual bin folder, the interop dll is *not* there!

How do i get it to be included? (I tried adding it as a reference and it wouldn't let me)

Comment: Are you able to run the website form Visual studio while debugging?

Comment: @vendettamit Yes. I fixed it by finding the interop dll and choosing "copy always"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the location of the `interop.dll` and add it to the project, then select `copy always`. This will force the publishing profile to copy it to your deployment.